# Bibtex does not create citation

Tags: bibtex, citing

First off, I am using TeXstudio, in case that information is important.

After searching for hours, I was so deseperate that I simply took the example from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18481/biblatex-online-reference-not-printing-all-information), tried to run it and it doesn't work. So what I have is this:

```
%bibtest.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=bibtex]{biblatex} %produces errors
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\title{Minimal test}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    Lorem ipsum ...\cite{Google5gram}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%

%biblio.bib
@ONLINE{Google5gram,
    author = {Alex Franz and Thosten Brants},
    organization = {Google Machine Translation Team},
    url = {http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/08/all-our-n-gram-are-belong-to-you.html},
    title = {All Our N-Gram are Belong to You},
    month = aug,
    year = {2006},
}
```

But the resulting document has no bibliography though the text has a citation tag.

[image]

And the compiler runs multiple times, always producing the same output:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
>  The top-level
>   auxiliary file: bibtest.aux
>  I found no \citation commands---while
>   reading file bibtest.aux
>  I found no \bibdata command---while
>   reading file bibtest.aux
>  I found no \bibstyle command---while
>   reading file bibtest.aux
>  (There were 3 error messages)
>  
>   Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)

I just don't know what I am doing wrong. I deleted all files except the two listed above, I restarted my IDE, rebooted my PC, nothing worked. I am desperate, please help!

Comment: I believe `biblatex` assumes `backend=biber` by default, so you need to run `biber filename`, not `bibtex filename`. Also, in `\addbibresource` you should include the file extension, so `\addbibresource{biblio.bib}`.

Comment: I am using TeXstudio, I hope it knows what to do, because I don't.

Comment: See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154754)

Comment: Alternatively you can add `backend=bibtex` to the options for `biblatex`, in which case `bibtex` will work.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. adding it to the options somehow magically destroys the project. The log says: _"Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:(biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavailable."_ and _"Use of \blx@bbl@verbadd@i doesn't match its definition. \verb"_

Comment: `biber` does have more features, which is what that warning tells you. I would guess that the error comes from an auxiliary file, and that if you remove all of them and recompile, it would work. But should also be quite easy to tell TeXstudio to use `biber`, cf. link above.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I just searched 30mins to figure out what this warning is trying to tell me and how to get rid of it. And you just hide it in this underrated comment. ;-) Thank god for googles incredible search capabilties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%bibtest.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cite}

 \title{Minimal test}
 \date{\today}

 \begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1] \cite{wang_model_2009}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}  
\bibliography{biblio}
 \end{document}

 %biblio.bib
 @book{wang_model_2009,
address = {London},
title = {Model {Predictive} {Control} {System} {Design} and  {Implementation} {Using} {MATLAB}®},
isbn = {978-1-84882-331-0},
publisher = {Springer London},
author = {Wang, Liuping},
year = {2009},
keywords = {Appl.Mathematics/Computational Methods of Engineering, (CAD, CAE) and Design, Computer-Aided Engineering, Control , Robotics, Mechatronics, Electrical Engineering, Engineering, Industrial and Production Engineering, Industrial Chemistry/Chemical}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Finally, a result I could build upon. Even the `@online` works as I want it to. Thanks! :D

Comment: @jaySon FYI, the example you posted in your question works perfectly when I compile with the sequence `pdflatex` - `biber` - `pdflatex`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the heads up. The thing is, I don't know how to handle a LaTeX compiler so I don't know where or how I would have to run this sequence. I am using an IDE (TeXstudio), because it does its "magic" when I press F5 so I don't have to worry about that. And even more problematic is that I am running out of time and thus get closer and closer to a state where I need things to "just work".

Comment: @jaySon I don't know if you looked at [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154754), but to make a somewhat recent version of TeXstudio run `biber`  go to Options --> Configure TeXstudio --> Build, and select `biber` as *Default bibliography tool*.  Also, the `backend=bibtex` version would probably have worked if you did Tools --> Clean auxiliary files first (should have mentioned that, sorry). But the most important thing is of course that you have a working solution (especially with deadlines looming.)